# Append CSV file to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to append this CSV file after the last row with data in this Google Sheet. But I can only overwrite the existing data.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'key.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

spreadsheet = client.open('upload_data')

with open('gmt2.csv', 'r') as file_obj:
    content = file_obj.read()
    client.import_csv(spreadsheet.id, data=content)
```

Answer (score 1):

When `import_csv` is used, it seems that the Spreadsheet is overwritten by the CSV data. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. In your situation, how about using `append_rows` method? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# I modified below script.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name you want to append the CSV data.
spreadsheet = client.open('upload_data')
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
content = list(csv.reader(open('gmt2.csv')))
worksheet.append_rows(content, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this case, `import csv` is used.

#### References:

- [`append_rows`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/ea353e43e5cdb4b7f8aa2c9ac4427c0ff3ffaba9/gspread/worksheet.py#L1061)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)